# Cannot get MongoDB C# driver to work with Subclass and virtual properties?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am working with MongoDB using C# driver.
The problem is that, I want to store different types of objects in MongoDB, with some common fields and different detail fields. Different clients handle different types in the database.

The code looks like the following:

```
class Things
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string User { get; set; }
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Dictionary<string, object> Details { get; set; }
}

class Pc:Things
{
    public new Detail Details { get; set; }
}

class Detail
{
    public string cpu { get; set; }
    public int ram { get; set; }
    public int hdd { get; set; }
}
```

When I do a query and try to get Pc objects out, it throws a exception saying that the Details property is used in the Things so it cannot be used in Pc. The expection is thrown during deserializing the object, I guess.

When I make another class:

```
class Pc2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Detail Details { get; set; }
}
```

which is the same as Thing, but with the Details as Detail type, everything works.

Am I doing this wrong? Or will this be possible in the future versions of CSharpDriver?

Answer (score 2):

[Clarification]

Rereading your question and comment I realize I addressed your problem wrongly. Your use of the new keyword is not illegal - the compiler will allow you to return a different type in a derived class with a property with the same name - what happens is that your telling the compiler that the derived class' Details property is *independent* from its parent class.

When you're doing this it's often a sign that your class hierarchy is not well thought out which is why I was so dogmatic in my initial post.

In your case (trying to store common classes with different `Details` in MongoDb) with a polymorphic class hierarchy you are running afoul of the MongoDb driver's serialization automapping. In order to do what you want you should use explicitly register your class' mapping as described in the MongoDb [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/). Quoting the relevant portion of the doc:

[Source: MongoDb documentation]

> The one case where you must call RegisterClassMap yourself (even without arguments) is when you are using a polymorphic class hierarchy: in this case you must register all the known subclasses to guarantee that the discriminators get registered.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think for my case I will have to rewirte the class.But since I cannot redefine the signature of the property to return a Class of Detail in a derived class, why does not the complier generating any error during compile time?

Comment: Thank you. You are right, my class hierarchy is not well thought out. I should remove the Details from the Thing class, and everything will work. If I want to handle things with arbitrary details, I will add class called "ThingsWithArbitraryDetails" derived from Thing, and with a Details property which is a dictionary.     But I have tried RegisterClassMap before, it did not help.

Comment: Hi - can you post a short sample with actual code using RegisterClassMap where deserialization is failing?

Comment: This is a really good response, which makes it even more sad, that it doens't include an example of how you would register those subclasses.

Comment: This is kind of a weird drive-by downvote - on a post from 2013: someone drives-by in 2016 and notes that although it's a really good response it's a shame no examples are provided so let's downvote it :p Just as an aside: my comment (from 2013) right above yours asked the original poster to provide an example of the failing code which he/she never provided.... /boggles